# Why comparison of biased representation are faster than two's complement?

Tags: binary, floating-point

Biased representation (or excess-N, offset binary) are used for floating number representation in computers. [This wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias) says

> This allows high speed comparisons

Could any one explain why comparison is faster (potentially in terms of gates implementation)?

Comment: Think of the length of a 2s complement number for a value in millions (or millionths, for that matter); now compare it to the size of a biased exponent representation.

Comment: @PeterSmith That is actually irrelevant to the OP's question. He really asks why the exponent is biased instead of simply stored as a 2-complement value like we're used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes it faster because, when you need to check if A is greater than B, with bias, you can just use the usual integer comparison (using subtraction), actually interpreting the floating point bits like a normal unsigned integer (like a "reinterpret_cast" in C++), and the result will be obtained immediately.

Otherwise, you would need two steps: first comparing exponents, then comparing mantissa, and that would make it a specific processor instruction.

Comment: Evident from my MC68060 manual, where every FPU operation takes 3 cycles except FCMP (floating point compare) which can be done in 1 cycle because of this.

Comment: But isn't integer comparison (or subtraction) one of the advantages of two's complement representation? Because all one needs is negation and addition.

Comment: Bias does not make it more complicated to do comparisons. The drawback of bias is when adding two numbers, you end up with a number with twice the bias. But you rarely need to add two exponents together. However, with bias, you can compare aller fields that compose the float in one shot. That is the point.

Comment: I'm still not very clear about "in one shot". Why do we need to care about the mantissa (if two's complement is used for exponent)?

Comment: If the exponents are the same, you need to fall back on comparing mantissa.

Comment: I see. But then why can't we always treat exponent + mantissa together as a two's complement integer, and do the normal two's complement comparison. It seems as efficient as biased representation.

Comment: No. To compare reals, you need to check their signs first. Then, if they are the same, their exponents, and then, if the exponents are the same, their mantissa. Therefore, if you want to be able to use traditional raw integer comparison, the leftmost bit *has* to be the sign. And after this, using two's complement for any of the exponent or mantissa fields would lead to inconsistent results. If you want a demonstration, just make up two positive numbers, one with negative exponent and one with positive exponent, and check the results of a raw comparison, you'll see the results would be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In an un-biased exponent representation, a "negative" exponent (for a number smaller than 1.0) would be represented with its sign bit set - true for any of 2's complement, 1's complement or sign&magnitude.

The consequence of this is that, viewed as a straight bit pattern, a small number would appear "out of order" i.e. "larger" than at least one number with a positive exponent (typically larger than all of them).

Then, the only way to compare FP numbers would be to unpack them, separately compare the exponents, mantissae and sign bits, and combine all these results with the appropriate decision logic.

But the biased representation chosen preserves strict ordering of all positive FP numbers (and only minor irregularities when you include signs) such that (using integer comparison)

```
0  
   < denorms (exponent=0)  
   < exponent=1  
   < ... 
   < 0.999999 
   < 1.0 
   < 1.00001 
   < ... 
   < (exponent = 0xFE) 
   < infinity 
   < NAN.
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation (and sorry for this late update). But why do we need to "unpack them, separately compare the exponents, mantissae and sign bits"? Isn't it enough to just compare signs and exponents, assuming there is a hidden 1.